# How to parse a large tree?

Tags: c++, tree

recently I passed a programming interview where I had to create a method that returns the address of a node (belonging to a tree). The method takes an integer value as an argument.

My code worked on a small tree, but when searching a large tree (300,000 nodes) I got an error stating "cannot access address '0x.....'".
What should I do to fix this?

'''

```
    struct Node
    {
        int value;
        Node* left = nullptr;
        Node* right = nullptr;
        Node* find_node(int);
    };

   Node* Node::find_node(int v)// The function is working on small trees only
    {
      if(this->value == v) //comparing the the value inside the root with the function's argument
        return this;
      else if(this->value > v) //if v is smaller than the node's value, search the next left node 
      {
        if(this->left == nullptr) //checking if the next node on the left exists
          return nullptr; //null returned if there is no more nodes
        else
          return (this->left)->find_node(v); //Call the find_node function recursively on the left node 
      }
      else if(this->value < v) //if v is bigger than the node's value, search the next right node 
      {
        if(this->right == nullptr) //checking if the next node on the left exists
          return nullptr; //null returned if there is no more nodes
        else
          return (this->right)->find_node(v);// Call the find_node function recursively on the right node 
      }
      return nullptr;// If the value is not found
     }
```

'''

Comment: Please turn the code fragment into a [mcve]. The shown code currently looks hardly readable to human beings and definitly uncompilable for a compiler. Applying some indentation would help.

Comment: Perhaps the calling code is attempting to dereference a null return value from this function?

Comment: I tried to explain the code, I'm new to this so I don't know how to do this minimal reproducible example, sorry!  I think you are right IronMan22, but I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: The given code looks reasonable. With 300,000 nodes you could be exhausting the the available Automatic storage if the tree is poorly balanced or you have a small amount of Automatic Storage.

Comment: Compile with higher optimization levels to optimize away the stack overhead of the tail recursive calls.

Comment: How to make a minimal reproducible example: 1. Back up your program. 2. Remove everything from the program that you do not need to expose the bug while still having a program that compiles and runs. Yes, this is more difficult than it sounds, but it almost always eliminates the need to ask a question. If you carry the MCVE all the way through, you wind up with a program that is a couple lines long, but you almost never need to go that far. Usually after a few halvings of the code size, there's so little room for the bug to hide that it leaps out and slaps you in the face.

Comment: Check for failed allocations. Handle exceptions. As long as you don't run out of memory or overflow the stack, this function looks okay to me. My money is on undetected failure allocating a node. (Side note, couldn't you just use std::set, and argue that it's already implemented as a tree?)

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I tested the code only on small trees it works fine, this is why I didn't try to modify it, however, when I did the codinGame test it didn't work on the large tree, I will try to create a large tree to test the code (but it will take some time).

Comment: The drawback of recursion is that does not scale to arbitrary data sizes. The stack size is constant and set during program compilation. A big data set with multiple recursive calls will eventually overflow it regardless of the total memory size. So you should write an iterative loop as the tail recursion is easy to eliminate.

Comment: IMHO, move the `find_node` outside of the `Node` class and into the tree class.  A `Node` is a single object and not a container of objects.  A *tree* is a container of `Node`s.  You can search a container, but it doesn't make sense to search a `Node` for a `Node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs lots of activation records on the call stack for repetitive calls to find_node(v). And it may lead to overflow of the call stack.

To avoid it, you can use non-recursive versions of binary search that uses a loop instead. For more information, check [this link](http://www.crazyforcode.com/write-code-search-binary-search-tree-bst/).

Comment: OP appears to have a binary search tree here, so there's no need to search the entire tree just to find a node. Also, I wouldn't link to a site which often have `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` as the first two lines in their programs.

Comment: @Alexander Zhang You are right. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Hoodi, apparently recursion always mess things up.